# Insert Label value using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="x in myData ">
    <div class="list-group ng-binding">
        <label for="Which is the cinema hall closest to your residence?"></label>Which is the cinema hall closest to your residence?
        <input name="email2" class="form-control ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="required" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-ng-required="isRequired" data-ng-model="quesAnsModel.answer[x.id]">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to Insert value of Textbox having Label ""Which is the cinema hall closest to your residence?" using VBA excel?

```
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-6 ng-scope").value
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking

Comment: Suggest how to fill Text box having labal name "Which is the cinema hall closest to your residence?"?

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a css attribute = value selector is nice and readable

```
ie.document.querySelector("[for='Which is the cinema hall closest to your residence?']")
```

**A label is normally just that**. If you in fact need the adjacent input box (though it says email?) you would use an adjacent sibling combinator to target the following input box

```
ie.document.querySelector("[for='Which is the cinema hall closest to your residence?'] + input").value = ""
```

Comment: I was shocked that the `querySelector`  returned a single input.  Wow+1.

Comment: @TinMan Yeah. The first match or null. querySelectorAll will return a nodeList or null.

Comment: Aww..I think that I have always used `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @TinMan I have no idea whether it makes any real difference efficiency wise between Selector and SelectorAll with index. I guess there might be. The main part  I consider is the efficiency of the selector and typing less!

Comment: I would think that `querySelector` would stop iterating over the document nodes at the first match and thus be more efficient then  `querySelectorAll()[0]`.  FYI: I just finished my rewrite of a `Craps Calculator` for work.  Replacing all instances of `getElementsByClassName()[0]` with `querySelector()` and using  `querySelectorAll()` to add events to multiple classes of controls at a time was the NUTS!!!

Comment: @TinMan You are likely to see a performance boost then unless using a really old IE version.

Comment: Perfectly Worked